# Loading two controllers inside another controller in ci

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I need to load two controllers inside a third controller, the problem is that the first one is loaded successfully, the second is not! I change the order of each of them same problem occur, the first is loaded the second is not.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTagsList() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\barkom\application\controllers\product_updating_controller.php on line 33
```

Here is the code

```
 public function index() {

 //load product info
    $this->load->library('../controllers/product_display_controller');
    $this->data['productMainInfo'] = $this->product_display_controller->getProductMainInfo(1, 'ar');

    $this->load->library('../controllers/product_management_controller');

    // get constants
    $this->data['tags'] = $this->product_management_controller->getTagsList('en');

}
```

Comment: You cant redirect to controllers from controller bro. The way you loading a controller is awesome, tell me more about it. Why you cant use the models directly from your controller?

Comment: @Nil'z why not?? I work on that but only with one controller! 
How about reusing the functions of other controller, how can we manage it??

Comment: Ever heard of `extending` controllers or `My_Controller` concept bro?

Comment: Extend controllers is not available, but loading other files is already exist in PHP, from this concept I m trying to do that!

Comment: I would recommend refactoring to make the secondary controllers libraries instead. Then any controllers that need them can load them, without you having multiple classes extending CI_Controller, which seems like a sure recipe for heartache.

Answer (score 0):

don't use that code if your changing controller.. try this

```
redirect('controller_name/method');
```

Comment: Please elaborate the answer and explain why it would be a good solution, so it is useful for others too.

Comment: because they're secure.. its determine if there are illegal character in the url, also it is not accepting parameter..that's why it is much secure